# How to expand the number of subuids for a linux namespace

Tags: linux, chown, namespace, unshare

After running something like this:

```
$ unshare -rUm
$ mkdir opt
$ mount --bind opt /opt
$ touch /opt/test
$ chown 1000:1000 /opt/test
```

I'm receiving this:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/opt/test': Invalid argument
```

As I can see, I only have 1 subuid that I can use.

```
$ cat /proc/self/uid_map
         0       1000          1
```

How can I add more than that?

I already have this in my subuid/subgid files:

```
$ cat /etc/subuid
cloud-user:100000:65537
```

Comment: Do you also have created an entry in `/etc/subgid`? The subuid entry looks correct.

Comment: Yeah, I also have that.